# making a simple sytem call for linux 2.6.39 kernel

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, system-calls

I am learning to make a simple system call from [this](http://vikasjadhav-lkp.blogspot.in/2012/03/adding-system-call.html) website.

When i go to my "/usr/src" directory, I see 2 folders

1) Linux

2) Linux-Source-2.6.39.4

To which one should i make changes in order to make my system call ?

Comment: The one called "Linux" is probably a symlink to the one with the version number.  But it'd help to mention what distribution you're using.

Answer (score 2):

Neither.  Download a [fresh copy of the kernel source code](https://www.kernel.org/), extract it into your home directory, and do your development work there using your normal user account.  You only need root to *install* the kernel after you compile it.

The root-owned files in `/usr/src` are probably associated with the stock kernel that came with your system, and shouldn't be used for development.  Especially since you'd have to do your development *as* root, just to have write permission.

Comment: But i have installed bactrack  with 2.6.39.4 kernel in virtual-box for this purpose only. So i don't care if anything happens to it. Should should i use "linux" or "Linux-Source-2.6.39.4". Also i guess i am root user while in backtrack

Comment: It's still not a good habit to practice.  If you want to use that 2.6.39.4 tree specifically, make a copy of it in your home directory and leave the one in `/usr/src` alone.